# I've got a multiline string in json from textarea input

Tags: javascript, php, sql, json, ajax

I try to code a little social network. So I have a form with textarea to write and send a post. Now if I want to write for example:
Hello this is the first line
and this is the second line

it's stored exactly like this in my database. Now if I want to output the post I query the database and form a JSON string. The problem is that the new line is also in the JSON string so of course I get this error:
JSON.parse: bad control character in string

I tried something with nl2br() but nothing really helped.

This is the code to form the json string with data of the posts from the database

```
$response = "[";
                  foreach($followingposts as $post) {
                          $response .= "{";
                                  $response .= '"PostId": '.$post['id'].',';
                                  $response .= '"PostBody": "'.$post['body'].'",';
                                  $response .= '"PostedBy": "'.$post['username'].'",';
                                  $response .= '"PostDate": "'.$post['posted_at'].'",';
                                  $response .= '"Likes": "'.$post['likes'].'"';
                          $response .= "},";
                  }
                  $response = substr($response, 0, strlen($response)-1);
                  $response .= "]";
                  http_response_code(200);
                  echo $response;
```

And this is the Ajax request to show the posts on the timelin

```
      $.ajax({
                      type: "GET",
                      url: "api/profileposts?username=<?php echo $profileusername;?>",
                      processData: false,
                      contentType: "application/json",
                      data: '',
                      success: function(r) {
                              var posts = JSON.parse(r)
                              $.each(posts, function(index) {
                                      $('.timelineposts').html(
                                              $('.timelineposts').html() + '<blockquote class="blockquote" style="margin-left:45px;max-width:650px;width:auto;margin-bottom:40px;"><p class="mb-0" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);">'+posts[index].PostBody+'</p><footer class="blockquote-footer" style="color:rgb(137,137,137);font-weight:500;">von '+posts[index].PostedBy+'<button data-id="'+posts[index].PostId+'" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="background-color:rgb(30,40,51);padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;margin-left:15px;border:none;"><i class="fa fa-heart" style="font-size:27px;color:rgb(255,0,0);"></i><span style="color:rgb(255,0,0);margin-left:15px;">'+posts[index].Likes+' Likes</span></button></footer></blockquote>'
                                      )

                                      $('[data-id]').click(function() {
                                            var buttonid = $(this).attr('data-id');
                                            $.ajax({
                                                type: "POST",
                                                url: "api/likes?id=" + $(this).attr('data-id'),
                                                processData: false,
                                                contentType: "application/JSON",
                                                data: '',
                                                success: function(r) {
                                                  var res = JSON.parse(r)
                                                  $("[data-id='"+buttonid+"']").html('<i class="fa fa-heart" style="font-size:27px;color:rgb(255,0,0);"></i><span style="color:rgb(255,0,0);margin-left:15px;">'+res.Likes+' Likes</span>')
                                                  console.log(r)
                                                },
                                                error: function(r) {
                                                  console.log(r)
                                                }
                                            });
                                      })
                              })
                      },
                      error: function(r) {
                              console.log(r)
                      }
              });
```

Comment: Why not use php's built-in JSON tool to encode your object as JSON?

Comment: To add to the above, the built in `json_encode` and `json_decode` functions will escape these things.  It dos a good job (except for non-UTF-8).  Also when you display the text you can simply use the css `white-space:pre` style and you don't have to mess with converting anything. Which comes with it's own problems, such as using htmlentities on the output if you have all these `<br>` tags in there or putting the modified data back in a textarea to edit it.

Comment: One last thing I hinted at above, if you are storing user entered content in the DB, you need to escape this content (with 'htmlentities' ) before outputting to "other" users.  If you don't you could allow 1 user to enter Javascript code into your DB that then is displayed to other users - which is ... bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you query with aliases for the column names then it is simple:

```
SELECT id AS PostId,
       body AS PostBody,
       username AS PostedBy,
       posted_at AS PostDate,
       likes AS Likes
       FROM table_name ....
```

Then fetch the rows into `$followingposts` as before and output the JSON:

```
echo json_encode($followingposts);
```

That's it.

If this is a CMS or application where you don't actually construct the query, then:

```
foreach($followingposts as $post) {
    $response[] = array(
    'PostId'   => $post['id'],
    'PostBody' => $post['body'],
    'PostedBy' => $post['username'],
    'PostDate' => $post['posted_at'],
    'Likes'    => $post['likes']);
}
echo json_encode($response);
```